# Como colocar no html a pagina no Google?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Gostaria de saber algum tutorial, como colocar a pagina na busca do Google e as demais paginas em baixo da "HOME" tipo:

Index

contato, serviços, fotos, vídeos.

tudo na pagina inicial do google? Igual no site baixaki que puxa todas paginas de uma vez...

acho que usa meta name do html não sei bem, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: http://www.agenciamestre.com/seo/google-e-o-uso-de-menus-internos-nos-mini-sitelinks/

Comment: Me desculpe, mas não consegui entender muito bem o que você quer.

Comment: Acredito que seja isso que ele quer: https://snag.gy/v34sY6.jpg